# Contional Formatting If match on other Spreadsheet with multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have 2 sheets Both contains Question ID, Question Links & Status but the 2nd sheet has a different layout.

**SHEET 1**
[image: Click here to show image of Sheet 1]

**SHEET 2**
[image: Click here to show image of Sheet 2]

The Code `=match($A:$A, indirect("Sheet 2!A:A"),0)` will match the 2nd sheet if the question id is already at the 2nd sheet and change its cell color but the `Q16` cant match the 2nd sheet even if I replace the code`=match($A:$A, indirect("Sheet 2!A:E"),0)`. Need some assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work.

I just a new rule on each cell `=match($A:$A, indirect("Sheet 2!E:E"),0)` 
if i hade a new column with Question ID i will just add new rule

```
EX: F:F G:G H:H
```